# How to make my JS callback work right?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have the following problem:

I'm trying to implement a Callback in JavaScript. Now I just made it with a global variable which holds my callbacl function. Here is the example:

```
_callbackFkt = null;

requestCompleted = function(oControlEvent) {
    console.log("Callback: " + _callbackFkt.toString());
};

myLibRequest = function(callback) {
    // some code, which is attached to the requestComplete event when ready
    _callbackFkt = callback;
};
```

Now I try to call the functions which use the callback:

```
myLibRequest(function () {
    // callback function 1
});
myLibRequest(function () {
    // callback function 2
});
myLibRequest(function () {
    // callback function 3
});
```

the result in the console is:

```
Callback: function () {
    // callback function 3
}
```

How can I define the callback to be bound to one function call and not global available? I want the result:

```
Callback: function () {
    // callback function 1
}
Callback: function () {
    // callback function 2
}
Callback: function () {
    // callback function 3
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you are trying to do, but your basic problem is that you want a list of event handlers, but you are only assigning a single value.

To modify what you are currently doing:

```
_callbackFkts = [];

myLibRequest = function(callback) {
  // some code, which is attached to the requestComplete event when ready
  _callbackFkts.push(callback);
};
```

Then, when you want to execute the callbacks:

```
_callbackFkts.forEach(function(callbackFkt) {
  callbackFkt();
});
```

But, this global mechanism is a bit messy.  You might consider some encapsulation (untested, but you get the idea):

```
function Events() {
  this.callbacks = [];
}

Events.protototype.bind = function(callback) {
  this.callbacks.push(callback);
};

Events.prototype.executeAll = function(params) {
  this.callbacks.forEach(function(callback) {
    callback.apply(this, params);
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var events = new Events();

events.bind(function() {
  //callback function 1
});

events.bind(function() {
  //callback function 2
});

events.bind(function() {
  //callback function 3
});

events.executeAll('with', 'parameters');
```

Finally, you might just use an off-the-shelf event library.  There are lots.  One quick google search finds [this](http://events-js.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Having a global as the callback will only work if `myLibRequest()` contains only synchronous code (which I assume it doesn't).

Remove the global, and use the `callback` that is passed in as an argument.

Assuming you have some async call in there, and you call `requestCompleted` when it's done. Add an argument so `requestCompleted` receives the callback, instead of referenceing the global.

```
requestCompleted = function(oControlEvent, callback) {
    console.log("Callback: " + callback.toString());
};

myLibRequest = function(callback) {
    myAsyncFunction(function(){
        // async complete
        requestCompleted('event', callback);
    });
};
```